# Is there a dirt-simple way to post code snippets in a StackOverflow answer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Is there a dirt-simple way to post code snippets in a StackOverflow answer?

I've been putzing around the with either the 'inline' code curly braces, or this 'indent 4 spaces' concept.  Still losing whitespace and/or wordwrapping where it shouldnt be.

Comment: Copy code, select it, Ctrl+K? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Well while the selected answere worked on some limited testing.  On this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631801/way-to-react-on-deleting-any-row-from-table-in-sql-server-2005/10956000#10956000, still unable to get the code to format properly if copy-pasted then using the curly braces.  You will see that instead, I linked to a posting on Microsoft Script Center.

Comment: Brand spanking new : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down Shift while you select the code block with either the mouse or arrow keys, this should highlight the block.

Now hit the `{}` button above the entry box, this should indent all the selected code by the necessary 4 spaces and also put blank lines before and after if necessary. You can see the effect immediately in the preview below the entry box.

Answer (score 2):

In your favorite code editor, ensure that the farthest left indent of the code that you are about to copy is *four characters from the left margin of the editor*.  Once you've done this, select and copy.  Then, when you paste in the editor, you're already done.

For example, in my case, I'll select my code (visual studio), hit shift-tab (decrease indent) until **at least one line of code has touched the left margin of the code editor**, then I'll hit tab once.  That adds *four spaces of indent to the code.*  I then copy and paste it into the question editor.